# How can I delete all jpg files except "1.jpg" in shell

Tags: linux, shell

In my Raspberry Pi, there are a lot of `jpg`files. I want to delete all `jpg` files except `1.jpg`. How can I do that in shell script?

Comment: Use a script that renames the exception, then deletes all files matching the name pattern and finally re-renames that exception file back to its original name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find), e.g.

```
find . -name \*.jpg \! -name 1.jpg -exec rm {} \;
```

Be very careful though, you can easily delete a lot of files unintentionally if you get this wrong. Do a "dry run" first to check which files will be deleted, e.g.

```
find . -name \*.jpg \! -name 1.jpg -exec echo "rm {}" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [extended glob pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) for negation (requires Bash):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls
1.jpg  2.jpg  name.jpg
$ ls !(1).jpg
2.jpg  name.jpg
$ rm !(1).jpg
$ ls
1.jpg
```